# TSQL Split Function to create multiple rows and columns (table valued function)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, split, csv, table-valued-parameters

I'd like to return an entire table from a string that uses two different text delimiters. Semi-colons for rows, commas for columns. A table valued function could do this but I am far too green to understand how to parse and then append the data to the pre-existing data set.

I would like to be able to accomodate a non-fixed number of columns in the dataset assuming that each row has the same number of columns as the others. It should be that the order the data sits in the string is the order that the columns come out. Hopefully, this mean broad applicability for delimited, indexed strings in the future.

Example (carriage returns added for clarity - this is a single string):

```
Master Section 1,Stuff 1,234345,3453453,23423423;
Master Section 1,Stuff 2,6786787,6576576,76577;
Master Section 2,Section 2 Stuff 1,898676,9870970,8708798
```

Becomes:

```
Column 1           Column 2   Column 3  Column 4  Column 5
---------          --------   --------  --------  --------
Master Section 1   Stuff 1    234345    3453453   23423423
Master Section 1   Stuff 2    678678    6576576   76577
Master Section 2   Stuff 3    898676    9870970   8708798
```

Ideally, the splitting function could accomodate as many columns as there are commas in the data set.

Current Split String Function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[splitstring] ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([item] [nvarchar] (500), rn int)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @item NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 Declare @rn int = 1

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @item = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList (item, rn)
  SELECT @item, @rn

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
  SET @rn = @rn + 1
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList (item, rn)
 SELECT @stringToSplit, @rn 

 RETURN
END
```

I am invoking the `SplitString` function right now using the following SQL query. This only splits based on a single delimeter and only returns a single column.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblRepeaterStage0(Item_Title, Section_Values)
SELECT s.Item_Title, s.Section_Values
FROM 
(
SELECT d.Item_Title, d.Raw_Repeater,
 c.item Section_Values, c.rn
FROM dbo.tblRawRepeater d
CROSS APPLY dbo.splitstring(d.Raw_Repeater, ';') c
) s
```

Again, I am hoping to adapt this function to accept two delimiters and then use those delimiters to split into rows and columns. The table valued function return would then need to be appended to the pre-existing data set.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is XML

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(2000) = 'Master Section 1,Stuff 1,234345,3453453,23423423;
Master Section 1,Stuff 2,6786787,6576576,76577;
Master Section 2,Section 2 Stuff 1,898676,9870970,8708798'

DECLARE @strXML VARCHAR(8000) = '<table><row><col>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,';','</col></row> <row><col>'),',','</col><col>') + '</col></row></table>'

DECLARE @XML XML = CAST(@strXML AS XML)

SELECT 
    line.col.value('col[1]', 'varchar(1000)') AS col1
    ,line.col.value('col[2]', 'varchar(1000)') AS col2
    ,line.col.value('col[3]', 'varchar(1000)') AS col3
    ,line.col.value('col[4]', 'varchar(1000)') AS col4
    ,line.col.value('col[5]', 'varchar(1000)') AS col5
FROM @XML.nodes('/table/row') AS line(col)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to dynamically name the columns?

Comment: @Shrout1, you can name the column in SELECT as you want, or you can insert into a table as you did in question.